# Определение положения ToolTip относительно PlacementTarget

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток. Вожусь с собственным представлением ToolTip. Вопрос в следующем. Есть ToolTip у которого свойство Placement установлено как Right. Если элемент на котором отображается ToolTip не приближен к правой границе экрана и достаточно места для его отображения то ToolTip отображается правильно, если же не хватает, то ToolTip отображается как будто его свойство Placement установлено как Left. Подскажите как можно узнать с какой именно стороны, в данный момент отображен ToolTip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно нашел решение, но оно не настолько изящно как хотелось бы.
Собственно, есть два варианта решения:

1. Для ToolTip установить свойство Placement как Custom. Далее к свойству ToolTip CustomPopupPlacementCallback прикрепить делегат:

   ```
   CustomPopupPlacement[] placeToolTip(Size popupSize,
                                       Size targetSize,
                                       Point offset)
   ```

   в котором описать варианты отображения ToolTip.
2. Второй вариант представляет собой определение размещения ToolTip относительно его родителя:

   ```
   private void ToolTip_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
                   if ((bool)e.NewValue)
       {
           Point p = (sender as ToolTip).PointToScreen(new Point());
           Point t = ((sender as ToolTip).PlacementTarget).PointToScreen(new Point());

           if ((sender as ToolTip).Placement == PlacementMode.Right ||
               (sender as ToolTip).Placement == PlacementMode.Left)
           {
               if (p.X > t.X)
                   (sender as ToolTip).Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
               else if (p.X < t.X)
                   (sender as ToolTip).Placement = PlacementMode.Left;
           }

           if ((sender as ToolTip).Placement == PlacementMode.Bottom ||
               (sender as ToolTip).Placement == PlacementMode.Top)
           {
               if (p.Y > t.Y)
                   (sender as ToolTip).Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
               else if (p.Y < t.Y)
                   (sender as ToolTip).Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Оба варианта работают, вот только как упоминалось выше, оба способа является не особо изящными.

Comment: Я бы закешировал `sender as ToolTip` в переменную.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю за замечание. Это просто набросок, которые показывает работу решения